# Merge seperate queries and export table to csv in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

EDITED:

For the following:

`x has_many: y` and `y belongs_to: x`

I made 2 variables:

```
shortlist1 = x.where(...)
shortlist2 = y.where(...)
```

How can I merge the two queries to get one database containing the filters from shortlist1 and shortlist2? Currently, the below does not work:

`finalList = x.joins(y)`

Ultimately, I would like to export the table to a csv using:

```
respond_to do |format| 
        format.csv { send_data finalList.to_csv, filename: 'my_csv'+Time.now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.csv'}
    end
```

This works for a query such as `finalList = shortlist1.joins(:y).where(...)`, but the csv does not combine the columns from y. Only the columns from x are displayed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

## It's been a while since I used activerecord but..from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

> 12.1.2.1 Joining a Single Association
>
> ```
> Category.joins(:articles)
> ```
>
> This produces:
>
> ```
> SELECT categories.* FROM categories
>   INNER JOIN articles ON articles.category_id = categories.id
> ```

It looks like you'll have to add the columns you need with `#select` or some of its variants (check if something like `#select_append` is defined for AR).

Comment: Also, I'm just realizing, is the way I'm doing this wrong.  I need to find a way to combine the 2 queries into one.